# Backup and delete registry with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How to backup all the registry and delete specific registry values on a remote server in PowerShell?

```
$Registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Computer)
$RegistryKey = $Registry.opensubkey($RegistryPath,$true) ## $True = Write
$RegistryKeyValue = $RegistryKey.getvalue($RegistryKeyName)

$RegistryKey.DeleteValue("$RegistryKeyName") 
Write-Output "Removed registry key ($RegistryKeyName) on $Computer  `r "
```

I have tried this but not working.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers $registryKey does not contained any value when i checked....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you look at the [PSRemoteRegistry](https://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/) module.  It simplifies working with a remote registry.

```
Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry
```

Example:

```
$Computer="Computer01"
$RegistryKey="SOFTWARE\Test\Test"
Remove-RegKey -ComputerName $Computer -Hive LocalMachine -Key $RegistryKey
```

Comment: Please note that, through no fault of the answerer, PSRemoteRegistry is not longer supported, and the [extension](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RemoteRegistry) shows it is de-listed. In any case, the link in the answer is also invalid since Codeplex shut down years ago. :(